# python-telegram-bot v13.11 incompatible with requests and urllib3 libraries using python3.12

Tags: python-requests, urllib3, python-3.12

Apparently, the appengine package which is in urllib3.contrib is not present anymore in the modern versions of urllib3 but it is still required using the framework python-telegram-bot v13.11 ([source telegram/utils/request.py](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/v13.x/telegram/utils/request.py#L44C16-L44C23) line 44).

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.contrib.appengine'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to solve it using a previous version of urllib3 next to the requests library.

`pip install urllib3==1.26.15`